# Where are private shopify apps deployed?

Tags: shopify

I know you can install apps on any server like your own or Heroku, etc. I am more interested in private apps (to which only your shop has access). Are they deployed on shopify itself? Or are they deployed like any other app? *IF* they are deployed on shopify's servers themselves, can a PUBLIC app be deployed there too?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Private apps are deployed the exact same way, the only difference is that you have a pregenerated permission for the shop so that access doesn't need to be authorized.

Typically private apps are used for one off scripts, not a real application that the shop owner would use (not always the case, but this is how I would recommend using them). If this is an app that needs to be hosted and the use will access I would suggest creating a partner account and making a 'real' app. There are no drawbacks and most of the tools (gems) are optimized for use with regular apps. It will also be easier to transition to an app for multiple stores in the future, if needed.

John Duff, API and Integrations team @ Shopify

Comment: Does Shopify offer app hosting in any way? i.e. is it possible to host an app within Shopify itself?